# lombok doesn't work even though it was added as a dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

I started my project with the Spring initializr and added the dependency lombok. My project worked without any problems. But after I deleted and reinstalled Intellij, it started to no longer recognize the annotations `@Builder` or `@Data`. But as I said before I reinstalled Intellij, everything worked fine.

My Error message:

```
2021-03-30 11:04:32.480  INFO 9516 --- [           main] c.e.B.BetterguardsJdbcApplication        : Starting BetterguardsJdbcApplication using Java 15.0.1 on Student60-PC with PID 9516 (C:\Users\b.ongün\Desktop\Betterguards_Jdbc (1)\Betterguards_Jdbc\target\classes started by b.ongün in C:\Users\b.ongün\Desktop\Betterguards_Jdbc (1))
2021-03-30 11:04:32.480  INFO 9516 --- [           main] c.e.B.BetterguardsJdbcApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-30 11:04:34.198  INFO 9516 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-03-30 11:04:34.573  INFO 9516 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 363 ms. Found 12 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-03-30 11:04:35.698  INFO 9516 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-03-30 11:04:35.729  INFO 9516 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-30 11:04:35.729  INFO 9516 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-03-30 11:04:36.172  INFO 9516 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-30 11:04:36.172  INFO 9516 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3567 ms
2021-03-30 11:04:36.610  INFO 9516 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-03-30 11:04:36.688  INFO 9516 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.25.Final
2021-03-30 11:04:36.938  INFO 9516 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-03-30 11:04:37.110  INFO 9516 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-03-30 11:04:37.657  INFO 9516 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-03-30 11:04:37.704  INFO 9516 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-03-30 11:04:38.360  WARN 9516 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.example.Betterguards_Jdbc.Model.CompositeKeyStationendurchlaufView
2021-03-30 11:04:38.360  WARN 9516 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.example.Betterguards_Jdbc.Model.CompositeKeyStationendurchlaufView
2021-03-30 11:04:38.360  WARN 9516 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.example.Betterguards_Jdbc.Model.CompositeKeyM_warenausgang
2021-03-30 11:04:38.360  WARN 9516 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.example.Betterguards_Jdbc.Model.CompositeKeyM_warenausgang
2021-03-30 11:04:38.360  WARN 9516 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.example.Betterguards_Jdbc.Model.CompositeKey
2021-03-30 11:04:38.360  WARN 9516 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.example.Betterguards_Jdbc.Model.CompositeKey
2021-03-30 11:04:39.126  INFO 9516 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-03-30 11:04:39.141  INFO 9516 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-03-30 11:04:40.001  WARN 9516 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-03-30 11:04:40.188  INFO 9516 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-03-30 11:04:40.360  INFO 9516 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [public/index.html]
2021-03-30 11:04:40.641  INFO 9516 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-03-30 11:04:40.657  INFO 9516 --- [           main] c.e.B.BetterguardsJdbcApplication        : Started BetterguardsJdbcApplication in 8.954 seconds (JVM running for 10.652)
2021-03-30 11:04:50.537  INFO 9516 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-03-30 11:04:50.537  INFO 9516 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-03-30 11:04:50.538  INFO 9516 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-03-30 11:04:55.629 ERROR 9516 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method builder() is undefined for the type Produktionsauftrag
    The method getErstellungsdatum() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getArtikelnummer() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getMenge() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getDsMin() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getDsMax() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getStatus() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getFertigungsdatum() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getKommentar() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getVersuchsnummer() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
] with root cause

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method builder() is undefined for the type Produktionsauftrag
    The method getErstellungsdatum() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getArtikelnummer() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getMenge() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getDsMin() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getDsMax() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getStatus() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getFertigungsdatum() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getKommentar() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest
    The method getVersuchsnummer() is undefined for the type ProduktionsauftragRequest

    at com.example.Betterguards_Jdbc.Service.ProduktionsauftragService.addProduktionsauftrag(ProduktionsauftragService.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.Betterguards_Jdbc.Controller.ProduktionsauftragController.addProduktionsauftrag(ProduktionsauftragController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: I oversaw that info, sorry, Please use specific from this link https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

Comment: Which IntelliJ version are you using? I'm currently using 2020.3.3 in combination with the same Lombok plugin version you're using and that's working fine.

Comment: @Thomas Kåsene  I am also using the intellij 2020.3.3 version and this isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to maven and click to clean. If you have import your project in eclipse, delete all files that was added from eclipse. That must be 3 files

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to install Lombok plugin into Intellij and set the option "Enable annotation processing" in the Intellij settings. Also your annotations seems to be weird, did you mean @Data instead of @data?

Comment: Yes I mean ```@Data```

Comment: i have already installed the plugin in intellij. You can look at the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You might need to enable the annotation processing in IntelliJ. `File->Settings->Compiler->Annotation Processors` check the `Enable annotation processing` checkbox then `Apply` and `OK`

Comment: I just checked and the check mark is “Enable annotation processing” was already set

Answer (score 0):

Make sure -javaagent:lombok.jar is added in the IDE STS.ini or eclipse.ini file